# How to phrase an answer, data is separated at the logic / programmatic / application layer?

Tags: sql, web-applications, coding-style, layer

How do I describe the partition of client data when all data is stored in one place and separated via programming?

If a collection of data from various clients is stored in a variety of SQL tables and is separated via the code (E.g. members from different orgs defined by organisation table) at which layer is the data separation defined?

Sorry if this question is a bit poorly worded.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of how to explain it, I'd need more information on how you're actually separating the data for consumption by different members, but we've done a similar thing using SQL views. In our case, it's pretty easy to explain because each role (i.e., a set of user permissions determined by their need-to-know) has a set of SQL views they have permissions to view and query but not modify. Then users can query the views as needed to make their own reports and datasets.

If you're looking for more technical jargon, [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905180%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) was one of the documents we came across when setting up our security.

It might be easiest to explain that each data element has a set of roles that have access to that data element. Your role within the multitude of client organizations determines which data elements you can work with in your reports. Then you would just want to use very strong language indicating how you have implemented safeguards ensuring that users cannot, in any way, access data that is not relevant to their need-to-know.